# Is it possible to send website invitee to google plus users

Tags: api, google-plus, google-hangouts

Is it possible to send website invitee to google plus users.

I have a website with option to login using google account. I want to send an message to all friends of logged in google users on logged in users request.

Comment: remind me NOT to log on to your website if your going to spam my friends I'm not going to be happy.

Comment: @Dalmo as asked message to be sent on users requst. No spam anyway, just want facebook like invite option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think interactive posts would be a good solution for this.
This allows users to choose themselves who and if they want to invite.

You can define an invite text that will be prefilled in the share box (even though users can adjust that text).

If you want you can also use the [`people.list`](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) method to fetch some of the more relevant friends and prefill the share box with them.

See https://developers.google.com/+/features/interactive-posts and https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive for details.